# Dump hex float in C++

Tags: c++, stl, hex, double, dump

I tried following:

```
std::cout << std::hex << 17.0625;
```

But it dumped it in decimal. I'd like to see 11.01 (17.0625 in hex). How can I print some floating point value in hex?

Please do not offer solutions like:

```
void outhexdigits(std::ostream& out, fp_t d, int max_chars=160)
{
    while(d > 0. && max_chars)
    {
        while(d < 1. && max_chars){
            out << '0';
            --max_chars;
            d*=16;
        }

        if (d>=1. && max_chars) {
            int i = 0;
            while (d>=1.)
                ++i, --d;
            out << std::hex << i;
            --max_chars;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to dump float numbers in hex in STL/boost?

Comment: Honestly, I find C++ to be quite annoying while outputting such formatted forms. In these cases, I use C style formatted print.

Comment: You will need to `memcpy` it into an `int`, and print the hex representation of that. `memcpy` is the only safe way to view the bits making up an object of one type as another type without hitting Undefined Behaviour (you hit unspecified behaviour instead, and it is up to you to know that the bits make up a valid `int` representation).

Comment: Do you want the hexadecimal representation of the memory layout of a `double` or to print a human-readable FP value in base 16?

Comment: Also, [`std::hexfloat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed).

Comment: @BoBTFish Wouldn't a `reinterpret_cast<int>(myFloat)` work in this case, instead of a `memcopy` ?

Comment: @JBL "`error: invalid cast from type 'float' to type 'int'`".

Comment: @BoBTFish Uh indeed, I thought I'd seen that somewhere, but apparently no. I think I interpreted the reinterpret cast as "see this set of bits as the low-level representation of the new type".

Comment: @JBL Maybe you saw type-punning through a pointer? `reinterpret_cast<int*>(&f);` However, this is just Undefined Behaviour, due to the aliasing rules.

Comment: @BoBTFish: You had the correct answer first, so undelete it.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, I need a human readable FP in base 16 in GCC and it would be nice if it works with boost::multiprecision

Comment: It looks like you are looking for "base 16 floating point" (which I've never come across, but OK it might be nice to have), in which case "11.01" would be: 1*16^1+1*16^0+0*16^-1+1*16^-2=16+1+0+0.00390625=17.00390625. 17.0625 would be 11.1.  Did I miss something? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Others have already suggested a C++11 solution but your question doesn't have the C++11 tag. Here is an ISO C99 solution, using the `%a` and `%la` format specifiers from the ISO C99 Standard.

> I'd like to see 11.01 (17.0625 in hex).

The following program prints `0X1.11P+4`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  double x = 17.0625;

  printf("17.0625 in hexadecimal is: %A\n", x);  

}
```

---

Here is an example showing how to read and write floating point numbers in hexadecimal format.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  double x = 0.1;

  char* str = "0X1.999999999999AP-4";

  printf("0.1 in hexadecimal is: %A\n", x);

  printf("Now reading %s\n", str);

  /* in a production code I would check for errors */
  sscanf(str, "%lA", &x); /* note: %lA is used! */

  printf("It equals %g\n", x);

}
```

If portability matters or you are stuck with an older compiler, it is a reasonable approach in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, its nice solution. However, I do not think it would ever work with boost::multiprecision. I'll try some boost::tr1 solutions before mark this as answer.

Comment: @Sergei I don't think there is any standard solution that would work with boost::multiprecision. [A quick google search](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boost-list/68ftUb1XRoM) seem to indicate that serialization support for boost::multiprecision is planned but not yet available within boost.

Comment: I'd expect P+1 vs P+4, apparently it's in bits not nibbles as I'd expect.

Answer (score 7):

Try `cout << std::hexfloat << 1.0625;`
This requires C++11.

Comment: according to this http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011 it have not been implemented in GCC yet. Any cross platform analog? boost::tr1?

Comment: Tried on GCC 5.3, it works. But still does not work with boost::multiprecision.

Answer (score 4):

[`std::hexfloat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) is a format manipulator to print floating point values in a hexadecimal representation. It has existed since the 2011 Standard.