# Why are std::hex and std::oct flags not working?

Tags: c++, hex, iostream, flags

This is my code:

```
// This program demonstrates the use of flags.

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string filename; bool tf; double number;

  cout << "Name a file to create/overwrite: ";
  cin >> filename;

  ofstream outfile (filename.c_str());

  if(outfile.fail())
  {
    cout << "Creating/Overwriting the file has failed.\nExiting...\n";
    return 1;
  }

  cout << "Give me a boolean (0/1): "; cin >> tf;
  cout << "Give me a large number with decimal points: "; cin >> number;

  outfile.setf(ios_base::boolalpha); // Turns on boolalpha flag.
  outfile << "Here's a boolean: " << tf << endl;

  outfile.unsetf(ios_base::boolalpha); // Unsets boolalpha flag.
  outfile << "Here's your number: " << number << endl;

  outfile.setf(ios_base::scientific); // Turns on scientific notation flag.
  outfile << "Here's your number is scientific notation: " << number << endl;

  outfile.setf(ios_base::fixed); // When possible, floating point numbers will not appear in scientific notation.
  outfile << "Here's your number in fixed notation: " << number << endl;

  outfile.setf(ios_base::hex); // Numbers will appear in hexadecimal format.
  outfile << "Here's your number in hexadecimal format: " << number << endl;

  outfile.setf(ios_base::oct, ios_base::uppercase); // Numbers will appear in uppercase, octal format.
  outfile << "Here's your number in octal format: " << number << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

When I run this...

[image: Linux Terminal]

Contents of **test.txt**:

```
Here's a boolean: false
Here's your number: 3491.67
Here's your number is scientific notation: 3.491670e+03
Here's your number in fixed notation: 3491.67
Here's your number in hexadecimal format: 3491.67
Here's your number in octal format: 3491.67
```

Why is it when I set the "hex" and "oct" flags, they do not work?

In the text file, I was expecting something other than "3591.67" next to "hexadecimal formal: " and "octal format: ".

Have I implemented the flags wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately octal and hexadecimal printing only works for integers, and not doubles. See http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/28-3.html

If you wish to use setf, it should be:

```
outfile.setf(ios_base::hex,ios_base::basefield);
```

. Alternatively, pipe in std:hex, i.e.:

```
outfile << std::hex;
```

.

Comment: I changed the variable "number" to an "int" type and the problem still persisted...

Comment: try outfile.setf(ios_base::hex, ios_base::basefield) ?

Comment: setf is overloaded to do two different things. setf(x) OR's x with the format flags, whereas setf(x,y), sets the format flags to (x&y). So the reason it didn't work may be because some of the other format flags, like from the scientific notation were set, but not `cleaned' off by the setf so it didn't behave as expected.

Comment: see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/fmtflags/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/setf/ , i am guessing as i am not completely sure.

Answer (score 2):

Octal and hexadecimal formats affect only how integers are displayed. If you want to see floating point numbers in hex you can use `hexfloat` (C++11) or use the `printf` function from `cstdio` with the `%a` formatting code.

See also [Dump hex float in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662859/dump-hex-float-in-c)

Comment: flags.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
flags.cpp:37:16: error: ‘hexfloat’ is not a member of ‘std::ios_base’
   outfile.setf(ios_base::hexfloat); // Numbers will appear in hexadecimal format.
                ^

Comment: hexfloat is part of the c++11 standard. Has the compiler been set to use it? For g++, you need to add --std=c++11 i think.

Comment: Nope... still not working...

g++ flags.cpp -o flags --std=c++11

Comment: @Evan: It depends on your compiler version. They didn't implement all of C++11 in one go. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59987